# Error while trying to create database with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PDP PDO, this is my code to create a database named "title"

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE title";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Database created successfully<br>";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage(); // THIS IS LINE NUMBER 17
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

But this is the error, which i get, while i try to run the script

```
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\database\createdb.php on line 17

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myDB'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: move `$sql = "CREATE DATABASE title";` to above `try {`

Comment: @Epodax Sorry, it is 'myDB' not movie. I edited the question.

Comment: I got this code from w3schools, their should not be any error.

Comment: Yes error doesn't fit it might be at `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=movie", $username, $password);`

Comment: w3schools! then the error is understandable

Comment: @bansi why? W3Schools is not one of the best websites?

Comment: This is a human error, it has nothing to do with W3Schools.

Comment: btw; are you trying to create a database or a table? Two different animals here.

Comment: that was a question ^ that needs to be answered.

Comment: You can't create a "database" within an "existing database", only a "table" in an "existing database". People have the misconception between both (different animals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connect to a db that is not existend here:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
```

remove the dbname:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername", $username, $password);
```

Comment: This one worked, thanks. But i got the code from w3schools.com. And it is really very good website. 

It is their fault??

Comment: @RahulSharma I can not say it without seeing the code

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp

Comment: @RahulSharma No, it is your fault. You were trying to access a database that didn't exist.

Comment: But the page says "Create a DB with PDO", why they wrote a code to access a DB? We can create a DB inside a DB?

Comment: @RahulSharma There are more than one example. The one you refer assumes that a db `myDB` exist

Comment: @RahulSharma No you can not have a DB inside of a db. But You can create an other DB if you loggin in with one DB

Comment: @Jens [This is what I asked the OP earlier...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305894/error-while-trying-to-create-database-with-php-pdo#comment75617199_44305894) - am not quite sure what they really want to do here.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot bro. Will select your answer as the best, once the time limit gets removed

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the SQL error on line #7 because you are trying to access `myDB` which doesn't exist yet and is throwing an exception.

You are getting the undefined variable error because the code in the `try` statement is failing before `$sql` is assigned to anything.